# Can I use the Context object in Android like the Spring (or Eclipse RCP) context?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have an `Activity` which has a couple other objects which are doing some work. Is there a convenient way to put shared objects into this `Context` object and use them elsewhere like I do when I use Eclipse RCP (e4)? Is this a good practice in Android terms?

I'm assuming that I do not switch activities, I'm just distributing work to other objects in my `Activity`.

I checked the API of `Context` but I did not find any obvious methods for this purpose.

Comment: It seems no. Context placeholder not providing any place holder http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a convenient way to put shared objects into this Context object and use them elsewhere like I do when I use Eclipse RCP (e4)?

When you subclass `Activity`, you are welcome to have data members in it.

> I'm assuming that I do not switch activities, I'm just distributing work to other objects in my Activity.

This sounds all the more like the role of standard data members and related methods.